# java light-weight debugger

Tags: java, linux, debugging

I'm looking for a light-weight java debugger - either in an IDE or standalone, command line or gui. I'm using ant and vim, and I've tried eclim, but eclipse runs too slow on my laptop to be an option.

When similar questions have been asked before, people have generally expressed that they don't like the command line ones but like the eclipse and IntelliJ ones.

Just wondering if anything has changed.

EDIT: Intending to try jdb and jswat.

Comment: It could be time to upgrade your hardware if eclipse or intelliJ are too slow to be usable. Even a decent second hand labtop should run these pretty well.

Comment: @Peter Thing is, that's the only thing I want to do that I have any trouble with, if speed irritated me on a daily basis I would upgrade. It's often in risky physical situations, so I'd need to spend quite a bit to get the build quality I need. They aren't completely unusable, but slow enough to noticably damage productivity

Comment: Until about two years ago I was sceptical as to whether faster hardware improved development productivity. Having used faster and faster machines I am convinced you should get the fastest available. e.g. My previous dev system was an 4.5 GHz i7 with 16 GB and a fast SSD and it was a pleasure to work on (cost around £1200 with two screens) My next I hope to be faster again. ;)

Comment: Particularly as a student, need to balance productivity and cost. I do love my 2 24" monitors on my desktop, but my laptop is so rarely noticably slow that it isn't worth the upgrade yet - I don't worry about how much better new computers are, I just look at the impact on my work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for command-line there's always [`jdb`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jdb.html). But I'm a fan of [JSwat](https://github.com/nlfiedler/jswat); it's a nice GUI tool for when you're not using an IDE.

Comment: What would you consider the pros and cons of each?

Comment: I haven't used `jdb` (well, maybe once 15 years ago to see what it was like), I'm lucky enough to have mostly been able to use GUI debuggers in my career (even 22 years ago, we'd use both monochrome and color monitors on DOS PCs so we could have the debugger on the monochrome while the program was on the color). JSwat has all the usual GUI advantages: You can see the full source code, browse it, set breakpoints anywhere, easily inspect variables, etc., etc. It's easy to connect to a running JVM (for servlets and such), but I expect `jdb` can do that easily as well.

Comment: JSwat was discontinued in 2013 and *"...is known* not *to work with Java 8 and possibly even Java 7."*